# Scrollbar shows up at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, user-interface, layout, margin

I'm creating an HTML document and after adding a new section a scrollbar appears at the bottom of the page probably something pushing the layout to the right.

I managed to scale down what causes the issue. It happens after I add the following code:

**HTML**

```
<section id="services">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="content-title">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Szolgáltatásaink</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content-title {
    padding-top: 4rem;
}

.content-title h3 {
    color: #333333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.content-title h3:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 15%;
    height: .4rem;
    background:  #ff5f06;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is the live app: https://avrasys.hu/

Comment: We'd need to be able to see more of your HTML markup and CSS styles to resolve this issue.

Comment: Uploaded the files to a liver server: https://avrasys.hu/

Comment: Add `overflow-x: hidden` this may solve your problem

Comment: @PapT You seem to be using bootstrap4 - read about [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/). _Pushed out content_ may occur if you use grid incorrectly: _In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at your live site https://avrasys.hu/ and found that removing `margin-left: -15px;` and `margin-right: -15px;` from the `.row` class fixes the issue.